# назовите зависимые и независимые члены словосочетания

Tags: синтаксис

назовите зависимые и независимые члены словосочетания разгребать деревянной лопатой рыхлый снег

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

разгребать деревянной лопатой рыхлый снег - комбинированное словосочетание с разными видами связи.

разгребать -  независимый член, являющийся стержневым в следующих сочетаниях со связью управление:
разгребать лопатой, разгребать снег;

лопатой -главное слово  в словосочетании на основе согласования - деревянной лопатой

снег - главное слово в словосоч. рыхлый снег;

деревянный и рыхлый - зависимые члены словосочетаний - и простых, и комбинированного.